# A basic JavaScript string comparison question

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I am encountering a problem with a string comparison using Node.js and its built-in `crypto` module (in the context of some signature checking for an incoming payload). Consider this code example:

```js
console.log(`
SIG   : '${signature}' - type: ${typeof signature}
HASH  : '${hmac.digest('hex')}' - type: ${typeof (hmac.digest('hex'))}
EQUALS: ${signature === hmac.digest('hex')}
`);
```

This is what I see in the console:

```
SIG   : '1406f5bfc078fa6a7feb5eca9c091a19c96926f6110272c04cd4cbd712be60c4' - type: string
HASH  : '1406f5bfc078fa6a7feb5eca9c091a19c96926f6110272c04cd4cbd712be60c4' - type: string
EQUALS: false
```

So, both are strings, as expected, and both are the same string. But why aren't they equal? I'm at my wits' end.

By the way, when using `==`, I also get `false` as result of the comparison.

> For information and h/t: I'm using this script as the basis: https://github.com/girliemac/slack-httpstatuscats/blob/master/src/verifySignature.js

Comment: did you tried to debugging in runtime?

Comment: @Deniz what do you mean by debugging in runtime?

Comment: For better visual representation do  `${JSON.stringify(signature)}` and `${JSON.stringify(hmac.digest('hex'))}`. It may reveal some hidden characters...

Comment: Compare the lengths. Maybe there is some invisible characters like @trincot said

Comment: @jfix try to add a `debugger` in the line above the compare evaluation and check the two values are really the same before they got printed out as `false`

Comment: Nice idea to check for `length`! The `hmac.digest('hex')` returns `0`! When I assign its output to a variable, it works as expected. Not sure why, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this issue because you've called `hmac.digest()` twice, the second time it returns an empty string:

Try to save the result in a variable then compare:

```js
const result = hmac.digest('hex')
console.log(`
SIG   : '${signature}' - type: ${typeof signature}
HASH  : '${result}' - type: ${typeof (result)}
EQUALS: ${signature === result}
`);
```

Comment: That's the one! Thanks for clarifying the duplicate use of `hmac.digest('hex')`.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use

```
var EQUALS = SIG.localeCompare(HASH);
```

Comment: Where is `SIG` defined in the OP's snippet, exactly?

Comment: SIG is just a string. the syntax highlight just failed up there